# Jquery Ajax page loads

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

hi i have the following code, that has a problem.

Every time i load the the script the first link loads in the div, however any other links wont load in the div.

Do i need to reinitialise the script after the Ajax call.

I am not an expert in jquery, or ajax. What i am trying todo is load all links into a div.

```
<div id="siteloader" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery('a').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();

   var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        $("#siteloader").load(href);
        success: initGenWidgets();
  });
});
</script>

<a href='http://tired.com/'>One</a>
<a href='http://www.bbc.co.uk'>two</a>
```

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (working and syntactically correct code) so we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
    $("#siteloader").load(href);
    success: initGenWidgets();
```

should be changed into this:

```
    $("#siteloader").load(href, initGenWidgets);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. however when i change the code, it fails to load any pages

Comment: how exactly it fails? what are the error messages, if you run it under Firebug or similar tool?